# Why HttpURLConnection.getInputStream stop working in Java

Tags: java, http

My program below stopped at the line:

```
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```

Neither error message popped up nor any output displayed on the console.
I am running Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.0 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4.

```
 public static void solveInstance(String instanceName){
            // solve a problem instance
            try{
                String query_url = "http://localhost:8807/scheduler";

                // read Request to a JSON Object
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject request = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(instanceName));

                // open connection
                URL url = new URL(query_url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                // POST Request
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw =  new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
                osw.write(request.toString());
                osw.close();

                // Get Response
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                while(( inputLine = in.readLine()) != null )
                {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();

                // Write response to a file
                JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(response.toString());
                String responseFile = /path_to_result/result.json;

                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(responseFile);
                fileWriter.write(jsonObj.toString());
                fileWriter.flush();
                fileWriter.close();

                System.out.println("Solved" + instanceName);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
```

I noticed that the similar question is asked  [InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream(); stop working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47826940/inputstream-is-httpurlconnection-getinputstream-stop-working)
but it was for Android and no solution was given there.

Does anyone have some idea on that? Do not hesitate to point out anything else wrong in my code.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What happens when you try to access `query_url` from a web browser?  It sounds to me like maybe your webapp is hanging.

Comment: _"My program below stopped at the line"_ -- What do you mean by "stop"? Your program cannot just stop executing with no message unless you had an empty catch block and threw away an exception.  Something must have been logged somewhere.

Comment: @JimGarrison It could block forever reading the response if it isn't sent and the server keeps the connection open and there isn't a read timeout at the client.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The webapp seemed work well -- I used Postman to post my Request and I got expected response. The problem happens when I use the above function, the execution will stop ( or hang forever? not sure) at the specified line. I have to use the above function because Postman cannot handle large Request (large JSON data). I tried Postman with small data only for your question.

Comment: @JimGarrison, I guess EJP is correct. By "Stop", I mean no response observable from the program. I am not sure what exactly it is and what is happening behind the scene:)

Comment: More info: If a terminate the service and wait for a while; then restart the service; then run the program, everything works fine; but if re-run the program right after a successful run, the program will stop at the given line of code.

Comment: Did I miss anything else in the code, e.g., should I somehow close the HttpURLConnection conn, Outputstream os, InputStream is, InputStreamReader isr?

Comment: If you have the server running locally you can always debug it and see what is happening. My bet go to some sort of unclosed stream in a statefull application using the same resources. One thing that I'm not sure it is related is that you are missing the content-length of your post request. something like `conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", String.valueOf(your data length here));`

Comment: @leo Closing the input stream is sufficent.

Comment: @JorgeCampos It isn't missing. The Content-Length is set automatically, and will be overridden if set manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your server isn't responding.

It would be wise to set a read timeout, with `conn.setReadTimeout(5000)` (say). Adjust the timeout as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Check response code

`int response = connection.getResponseCode();`

If you get 301 it means that your resource is redirected. Try to change URI from http to https.

It helped in my case.