# How to repeatedly post and get response from Http Service in Java?

Tags: java, http

I am trying to repeatedly access a Http service "scheduler". In each access, I want to post a JSON request to the service and get a JSON response from the service.

However, HttpURLConnection.getInputStream() refused to work, i.e.:

The first call of

```
solveInstance(instanceName);
```

worked fine, but the second call was stuck at

```
 InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```

By "stuck" I mean the program gave neither error message nor any output. I am not sure what exactly it is and what is happening behind the scene :(

Here is the code.

```
public static void solveInstanceSet(String instanceSetName) {
        // run each instance in an Instance Set         
        try {
            // get the instanceSet File
            File instanceSet = new File(instanceSetName);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(instanceSet);

            // solve each instance in the file
            while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                String instanceName = scanner.nextLine();
                solveInstance(instanceName);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: Cannot read the File contains the Instances to run!");
        }
    }

public static void solveInstance(String instanceName){
    // solve a problem instance
    try{
        String query_url = "http://localhost:8807/scheduler";

        // read Request to a JSON Object
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject request = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(instanceName));

        // open connection
        URL url = new URL(query_url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // POST Request
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw =  new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
        osw.write(request.toString());
        osw.close();
        os.close();

        // Get Response: a schedule
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while(( inputLine = in.readLine()) != null )
        {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        is.close();

        // write Response to a file
        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(response.toString());
        String responseFile = 
                "C:\\Path_To\\Result";

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(responseFile);
        fileWriter.write(jsonObj.toString());
        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();

        System.out.println("Solved" + instanceName + ".");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

What did I miss in my code?

Note:
I raised a related question [Why HttpURLConnection.getInputStream stop working in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49419412/why-httpurlconnection-getinputstream-stop-working-in-java). There, the problem is for only one call of the function. Please also read my comments there for more information.

Comment: adding your server implementation would certainly help

Comment: try to append this after the conn initialization.
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);   and last conn.disconnect();

Comment: so, (1) add conn.setDoInput(true) in the block "open connection"; (2) conn.setDoOutput(true) is already in the block; (3) add conn.disconnect() in the block right above "write Response to a file", right?